# Préposition devant un infinitif qui est dans un complément circonstanciel

Tags: prépositions, infinitif

Faut-il *à* ou une autre préposition devant un infinitif qui est dans un complément circonstanciel, particulièrement un [circonstant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circonstant) ([adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar))) ?

<sub>Source: Livre 4, *Émile* (1762) par Jean-Jacques Rousseau.</sub>

> Mais si, comme on n'en peut douter, l'homme est sociable par sa nature, ou du moins fait pour le devenir, il ne peut l'être que par d'autres sentiments innés, relatifs à son espèce ; car, **à** ne considérer que le besoin physique, il doit certainement disperser les hommes au lieu de les rappro¬cher.

Si la réponse est compliquée, simplement adressez-moi à un livre avancé de grammaire ou la recherche de la linguistique.

Comment: @Laure Je vous remercie de votre clarification et j'ai modifié le titre. Je ne connais pas le mot français pour le terme de syntaxe 'Adjunct'.

Comment: Adjunct = complément circonstanciel.

Comment: Je comprends *à ne considérer que le besoin physique* comme « si on considère que le besoin physique ». Mais peut-on aller jusqu'à comprendre « à force de ne considérer que le besoin physique » ? Il peut y avoir une petite différence mais je ne suis pas assez familière avec l’œuvre de Rousseau pour me prononcer. Mais de façon plus générale je ne pense pas qu'il faille toujours une préposition devant un infinitif complément, ça dépend....

Answer (score 1):

On peut employer quelques prépositions devant un infinitif, d'autres nécessitent d'autres formes :

- en + participe présent;
- après + avoir / être + participe passé.

Certaines ont besoin d'autres éléments, comme de:

- avant de manger.

D'autres n'ont pas de forme:

- pendant, sur, sous,

**Formes préposition +  infinitif:**

- à + infinitif = en faisant ...
- pour + infinitif = afin de
- sans + infinitif
- il y en a peut-être quelques autres ...

**à considérer = en considérant, ou si on considère que**

comme l'indique Laure, *à considérer* peut être pensé comme *à force de considérer*.

On emploie fréquemment le contraire avec *à*

sauf à penser que, sauf à affirmer que, sauf à prouver que = sauf si on pense que, ...

Answer (score 1):

Ça dépend directement du type de complément/circonstant (adjunct). Certains verbes sous-catégorisent des compléments avec des prépositions spécifiques qu'on retrouve dans les cas où ces compléments sont des infinitives :

- Paul pense *à* Marie/partir
- Paul vient *de* Paris/partir

Même chose avec les circonstants qui ne sont pas dépendants du verbe.

- Paul arrive *sans* les fleurs/acheter de fleurs
- Paul a donné ce livre *pour* Marie/faire plaisir à Marie

Ce type d'adjoint est aussi possible avec des noms ou des adjectifs :

- une pâte *à* mâcher, une envie *de* comprendre, une heure *sans* parler, un verre *pour* arroser
- facile *à* comprendre, difficile *de* marcher sur les mains, généreux *sans* compter, agréable *pour* parler